# Why doesn't Googlebot index pages it crawls?

Tags: indexing, search-engine, web-crawler

Three months ago I published my small personal website (~10 pages), submitted the URL to Google, and a few days later Googlebot showed up. Over the course of the last couple of weeks, Googlebot visits my website approximately twice a week and crawls maybe every other page.

Ever since Googlebot first crawled my website, whenever I run a search for `site:example.com` Google returns only my homepage. (Interestingly, so does Bing, so maybe the problem isn't specific to Google.)

I built the website with CodeIgniter mainly to familiarize myself with it. It's really simple, only a couple of pages about me and my projects. I am not using any black-hat SEO techniques, JavaScript, or anything like that.

What could be possible reasons why Googlebot would crawl my pages but not index them?

EDIT:
I do have a Webmaster Tools account. There are no crawl errors, internal links are listed, but listed keywords come only from my homepage.

Answer (score 4):

- Create XML site map and "tell" to Google about it in Google Webmaster tool
- Ensure your 10 pages have distinguished content - since search engine can eliminate if content looks identical
- Ensure links from home page lead to all another 9 pages. If so place link in

Comment: +1 for mentioning the Webmaster tool. It's the most reliable way to tell whether Google has a problem indexing a site.

Comment: Googlebot has no problem finding the pages. According to my logs, it does visit other pages on the website -- for some reason it just doesn't index them.

(1) AFAIK this shouldn't be necessary if links to other pages are easily discoverable, as they are in my case, but I guess submitting a sitemap won't hurt.
(2) Individual pages are very different. 

(3) I have the same navigation menu on all pages.

Comment: @MiseryIndex I think googleboot indexes +9 pages without any problem, but it "think" that these pages has no unique content in comparison with home. So you have solve: why I need 10 pages but not 1? If you will use advanced search option with google, you can see "Show with duplicated result" - try to expand this.

Comment: The pages are totally different. Show duplicated results... Do you mean `In order to show you the most relevant results, we have omitted some entries very similar to the 1 already displayed.
If you like, you can repeat the search with the omitted results included.` like on this page http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=site%3Aexample.com ?

Comment: If so, there is no such link when I search for my website.

Comment: @MiseryIndex definitly not. I'm using signed in version of google under the Chrome. In the top there is "+" to show duplicated, and at left there is a tree of advanced options of search.

Comment: I see no plus sign to show duplicated at the top even if I sign in to Google. If it's not too much trouble could you post a screenshot?

Comment: @MiseryIndex Here is the my screenshot http://picasaweb.google.com.ua/lh/photo/1GbpVxrWI7wmdl6B2d8zEA?authkey=Gv1sRgCMD26JyN0Yed7gE&feat=directlink
    Where my mark 1 - shows more options, 2 - shows more results for search

Comment: Hmm... I see no such links when I search for my site, but they do show up when I use your query. Must be something else. Thanks for trying though. :-)